# how to call function in background codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My system needs to send email to many users, and it really takes time to send many users. I do not want users to wait that time.

_send_mail functions are in various controller file per purpose. Is there any way we can send email in background?

Comment: use cron to send email.

Comment: You can use crons for send email in background.

Comment: Study about `Gearman`

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you can return a partial response before sending your mail. So you will get a response to proceed further and your email sending process will continue in the background.

To do this create a function which will throw a partition response like this

```
    function partialResponse()
    {
        $response=array();
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        ob_start();
        echo json_encode($response);
        header("Status: 200");
        header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 Ok");
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
        ob_end_flush();
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
```

and call this function before sending email

```
 $this->partialResponse();
```

after this DO whatever you want to do i.e Send the email

NOTE: This is tested with apache server only.This will not work for nginx.