# In Laravel, how can i send an email asynchronously from a controller without using (Queues & Jobs)?

Tags: php, laravel, email, asynchronous

I want to send an email after a user is registered right away without the delay that is caused by the Mail::send().
I don't want to send the email after seconds, i want it to be sent right away but without blocking the controller that is sending it, and for the love of Laravel don't suggest (Queues & Jobs) please.

Comment: I think you can do it using Queues. Because php doesn't have the non-blocking I/O feature. So you must have to use queues aka scheduler .

Comment: If you have enough queue workers, that is the best way. If you can't use queues for whatever reason, then [output control functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) are your only choice.

Comment: What's wrong with queues/jobs? Done properly, it should be basically instant.

Answer (score 1):

Until now i found 2 ways to deal with this :

**fastcgi_finish_request :**
I can use `fastcgi_finish_request()` but only after i have returned/echoed the view (I'm using Laravel), in this case i have to change the structure of my code to handle different situations. and of course in conjunction with `error_get_last()` if anything goes wrong.

[**laravel-async-mail :**](https://packagist.org/packages/ognjen/laravel-async-mail#v1.0.0)
Surprisingly i found that on Packagist.com, seeing the source code it start a new Process to initiate an artisan command. (I hope someone can give an opinion if this have a downside in production environment or not).
My choice for now is this one since it does exactly what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications) to avoid jobs. But you still need to setup queues for it to be asynchronous.

```
$user->notify(new OrderPuchased($order));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial response in this case(If you are using apache web server)

refer this for more info.

[how to call function in background codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113382/how-to-call-function-in-background-codeigniter/42113938#42113938)